# Best Practice for API Updates using Retrofit with CustomAdapters for RecyclerView

Tags: android, retrofit, android-recyclerview

I am using retrofit to get data from an API for a RecyclerView by passing it to a custom adapter within a fragment. In the adapter I have an inner class for the views and have implemented click events for the RecyclerView items.

What I want to know is what's the right way to make further calls using retrofit to an API for updates on items in the list etc. Is it "best practice" to make the calls either in the custom adapter or to do it from the Fragment or Activity its in.

Below is the basics of my custom adapter, keep in mind it doesn't have everything in there that I thought wasn't neccessary for the question.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private static List<ListItem> list = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> list) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = list;
    }

    // common stuff omitted for brevity

    // bind view holder
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem list = this.list.get(position);

        // setup the click handlers
        holder.setClickListener(new MyViewHolder.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, final int pos, boolean isLongClick) {

                if(v == v.findViewById(R.id.dream_button_suggestion)) {
                    if (isLongClick) {
                        // View v at position pos is long-clicked.
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Long clicked at position: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // View v at position pos is clicked.
                        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked at position: " + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        /**
                        *
                        *    HERE is where I would make call to api
                        *
                        */

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnLongClickListener {

        // initialize variables here
        TextView text;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // set variables to view items
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        /* Interface for handling clicks - both normal and long ones. */
        public interface ClickListener {
            /**
             * Called when the view is clicked.
             *
             * @param v view that is clicked
             * @param position of the clicked item
             * @param isLongClick true if long click, false otherwise
             */
            public void onClick(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick);
       }

        /* Setter for listener. */
        public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If not long clicked, pass last variable as false.
            clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // If long clicked, passed last variable as true.
            clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), true);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapter is probably not the best place to implement this kind of logic, instead you should have a mechanism that will allow you to notify your Activity/Fragment that an item in the list was clicked. You can do it using a custom interface, that is implemented by Activity/Fragment, or using an event bus implementation - there are multiple ways to achieve this.

Comment: Is there are best practice to this or is it just a matter of preference? And how would you update the list item object from the fragment?